# How do I programmatically get Google SEO/Search Rank information? API or Scraper?

Tags: google-search-api, scraper

I'm trying to find a programmatic way to get 2 values:

- a domain's position in the Google results for a specific term
- the number of Google results for that term

Currently my client is using some scraper software, but there's a manual step involved.

Is there an API I can access that will get me this info?  Or should I explore some fully automated scraper method?

(I know this has been asked before, but my question is a little different. Also I'm curious if things have changed since the question was asked previously.) Thanks!

Comment: Since this answer is closed I'll just add that in 2021 the best resource for this is the Google Search Console: https://search.google.com/search-console/.  Once you verify your site with Google, you can then use various NPM libraries which hook up to Google APIs (eg. `google-api-nodejs-client`) to access the information from the search console programmatically, and there is a *wealth* of information about your site's "SEO" available there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your left up to scraping...

there are some apis but they never have everything but

SEMRush (paid api)
http://www.semrush.com/
 or 
ShutKeys (free)
has json export of ranking for free
http://shutkeys.com/cartercole.com

Answer (score 0):

You can find an open source PHP based rank checker for Google at http://rank-checker.squabbel.com
You can download the source code directly from there and use it a console based PHP script.

You'd likely want to add MySQL/database support and some sort of in/out queue for keywords/domains.

Answer (score 0):

We have had great experince using the SEMRush API for this.  We actually built http://www.rankpop.com/rankalizer which was with that tool and gives a lot of Google ranking data.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The [above link](http://www.rankpop.com/rankalizer) doesn't work, no webserver exists, and I can't get any rankpop.com-based link to work. Is the service dead? And is there any substitute, or alternative?